# Diffrence between AllowDuplicateValues and EnforceUniqueValues?

Tags: field-definition

When defining a site column in XML, what is the difference between AllowDuplicateValues and EnforceUniqueValues?

```
AllowDuplicateValues="False"
EnforceUniqueValues="True"
```

Logically it should do the same, if I'm thinking right?

*Some intrestring links*

[msdn documentation - Field Element (Field)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx)

[msdn documentation - SPField.EnforceUniqueValues Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.enforceuniquevalues.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Docs, the best answer to me is that the AllowDuplicateValues attribute is used when defining the field in XML code while the other is used when writing .Net code.

Comment: I also agree with Spevilgenius.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is right in so far as the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx) say to use AllowDuplicateValues in CAML schema and EnforceUniqueValues in code.

The documentation is wrong, though; to make the CAML work you need to use the EnforceUniqueValues attribute.